# GeoServer incorrect CQL between filter?

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to make a `GetMap` request with a multiple `cql_filter` as following:

```
http://localhost:52459/handlerGeoserver.ashx?
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetMap&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
TRANSPARENT=true&
LAYERS=v_expedientesmapa&
cql_filter=(Year between (2017,2022)) AND IdEstadoPublico IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)&
time=1582632261553&
CRS=EPSG%3A25830&
STYLES=&
WIDTH=1656&
HEIGHT=1361&
BBOX=407077.33718499093%2C4550658.264466829%2C817875.6737958044%2C4888276.945703131
```

I'm getting filter parsing error. What is wrong with that filter? I'm using the [official documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) for this

**Edit:**

*Partially solved adding a double filter (year > 2017) AND (year < 2022)*

GeoServer logs:

```
Caused by: org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "between ( 2017 ," at line 1, column 7.
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    ":" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "." ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    ")" ...
    "not" ...
    "in" ...
    "tequals" ...
    "before" ...
    "after" ...
    "during" ...
    "like" ...
    "ilike" ...
    "exists" ...
    "does-not-exist" ...
    "is" ...
    "between" "(" "(" ...
    "between" "(" "[" ...
    "between" "(" <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "between" "(" <DATE> ...
    "between" "(" <DATE_TIME> ...
    "between" "(" "-" ...
    "between" "(" <INTEGER_LITERAL> "*" ...
    "between" "(" <INTEGER_LITERAL> "/" ...
    "between" "(" <INTEGER_LITERAL> "+" ...
    "between" "(" <INTEGER_LITERAL> "-" ...
    "between" "(" <INTEGER_LITERAL> ")" ...
    "between" "[" ...
    "between" <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "between" <DATE> ...
    "between" <DATE_TIME> ...
    "between" "-" ...
    "between" <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    "between" <FLOATING_LITERAL> ...
    "between" <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "between" "true" ...
    "between" "false" ...
    "between" "point" ...
    "between" "linestring" ...
    "between" "polygon" ...
    "between" "multipoint" ...
    "between" "multilinestring" ...
    "between" "multipolygon" ...
    "between" "geometrycollection" ...
    "between" "envelope" ...
    "between" "srid" ...
    "=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    ">=" ...
    "<=" ...
    "<>" ...
     Parsing : (Year between (2017,2022)) AND IdEstadoPublico IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,9).
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.compileFilterList(ECQLCompiler.java:122)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.CompilerUtil.parseFilterList(CompilerUtil.java:224)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toFilterList(ECQL.java:177)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toFilterList(ECQL.java:159)
    at org.geoserver.util.XCQL.toFilterList(XCQL.java:31)
    at org.geoserver.ows.kvp.CQLFilterKvpParser.parse(CQLFilterKvpParser.java:26)
    ... 102 more
```

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button - you may need to turn the logging level up to Geotools-dev to get a useful message

Comment: Done @IanTurton. it seems that I'm not correctly using the between function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used that way it's just calling a function, it's an expression, not a filter.
Use the between filter operator instead:

`(parseInt(strSubstring(Date,0,4)) between 2015 AND 2022) AND Id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

Comment: Question edited, still not working. So weird behaviour!

Comment: needs AND not , between the date arguments

Comment: there seems to be no way to convince CQL to recognise the between function - it always sees it as the OGC comparison operator

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton and Andrea, really appreciate it.

Comment: Indeed functions are available in multiple scenarios, like for example XML OGC filters too. This one has a name clashing with a CQL keyword, don't think there is a way to make it work as a function.